# Inducing quotients space and show the linear mapping

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

Suppose U is a subspace of V invariant under a linear transformation T :
V → V . Prove that T induces a linear map $\bar T : V /U → V /U$ of quotients given by $\bar T(v + U) = T(v) + U$. Prove that the minimal polynomial of $\bar T$divides the minimal polynomial of T.

I find similar question here but I am confused why it tries to show isomorphism since it is asked to show linear map. Do I miss anything? And for the quotient space linear mapping,
$$ T(u + v) = T(u) + T(v) $$
 for all $u, v ∈ V$
$$T(av) = aT(v)$$for all $a ∈ F$ and $v ∈ V$

How should it fully be shown?

[Inducing a Linear Transformation on the Quotient Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201458/inducing-a-linear-transformation-on-the-quotient-space?rq=1)

Comment: In view of the first problem, you need to show well-definedness.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I didn't see in the textbook. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $v+U = (v+u)+U$ for each $u\in U$. The first step is to show that $\bar T(v+U) = \bar T(v+u+U)$ using the invariance of $T$. This gives well-definedness.

Addition is obvious: 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\bar T((v+U)+(w+U)) &=& \bar T((v+w)+U) = T(v+w)+ U \\
&=& (T(v)+T(w))+U = (T(v)+U)+(T(w)+U) \\
&=& \bar T(v+U) + \bar T(w+U).
\end{eqnarray*}

Scalar multiplication is similar.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. So the well-definedness should be shown before the two axioms?

Comment: Indeed, well-definedness should be shown before the application of the operations.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the well-definedness? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The cosets $v+U$ and $(v+u)+U$ for $u\in U$ are the same. So they should have the same image: $\bar T((v+u)+U) =T(v+u)+U = (T(v)+T(u))+U =T(v) + (T(u)+U) = T(v)+ U$, since $T(u)\in U$ by assumption and so $T(u)+U=U$.

Comment: Thank you! But why we need this?

Comment: The mapping $\bar T$ is defined by taking a representative of the coset $v+U$. All other elements of the coset are of the form $(v+u)+U$ with $u\in U$. So one could choose another representative, but the image must be the same.

Comment: For the multiplication, $\alpha \bar T(v+U)=\alpha T(v)+\alpha U= T(\alpha v)+\alpha U$ and $\alpha U= U$. Can I just pull $ \alpha U$ directly inside the parathesis?